# Cannot have plivo send sms working

Tags: php, authentication, curl, plivo

I'm using Plivo PHP library to send sms via plivo.

I'm setting the correct auth credentials in the library and it is base64 encoded as per the library in curl_request method.

I think the headers are correct and My integration with my platform works fine but when trying the send a simple message with send_message method, I cannot have it working and always get a response status 401 which is, [as per the documentation](https://www.plivo.com/docs/api/response/), an error of authentication.

What Am I doing wrong ?

Many Thanks

My code:

```
//Load library messages
                $this->load->library( 'Plivo' );
                $p = new RestAPI( 'MANXXXXXXXXXXXXXZIWOD', 'MmXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' );

                // //for each phone Numbers generate password associated to event
                foreach ( $nums as $key => $num ) {
                    //For each combo send Message
                    $params = array(
                            'src' => '13307782635', // Sender's phone number with country code (US)
                            'dst' => '447598XXXXXX', // Receiver's phone number with country code (UK)
                            'text' => 'Hi, Message from your fired', // Your SMS text message
                            'url' => site_url( 'eventPromotion/report' ), // The URL to which with the status of the message is sent
                            'method' => 'POST' // The method used to call the url
                        );
                    // Send message
                    $response = $p->send_message($params);

                    // Print the response
                    echo "Response : ";
                    var_dump( $response );
```

Answer (score 9):

Instead of library use can use api.

```
<?php
    # Plivo AUTH ID
    $AUTH_ID = 'AUTH_ID-GOES-HERE';
    # Plivo AUTH TOKEN
    $AUTH_TOKEN = 'AUTH-TOKEN-GOES-HERE';
    # SMS sender ID.
    $src = 'SM123';
    # SMS destination number
    $dst = 'MOBILE-NUMBER';
    # SMS text
    $text = 'Hello';
    $url = 'https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/'.$AUTH_ID.'/Message/';
    $data = array("src" => "$src", "dst" => "$dst", "text" => "$text");
    $data_string = json_encode($data);
    $ch=curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $AUTH_ID . ":" . $AUTH_TOKEN);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
    $response = curl_exec( $ch );
    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($response);
?>
```

Change following params in code

```
AUTH_ID-GOES-HERE
AUTH-TOKEN-GOES-HERE
MOBILE-NUMBER

Note: Please make sure upload this code to live server in localhost it is not working
```

Comment: great no need to use vendor library.

Answer (score 0):

For sending sms in Plivo using curl, you will get return proper JSON from plivo api

```
$auth_id = 'auth_id';
$auth_token = 'auth_token';
$src = '+1XXXXXXXXXXX';
$dst = '+1XXXXXXXXXXX';

$text = 'Hello, this is testing message';

    $api = curl_init("https://api.plivo.com/v1/Account/$auth_id/Message/");
    curl_setopt_array($api, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
        CURLOPT_POST => 1,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("Authorization: Basic ".base64_encode($auth_id.':'.$auth_token)),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
            'src' =>$src,
            'dst' => $dst,
            'text' => $text
        )
    ));

    $resp = curl_exec($api);

    $resp = curl_exec($api);
    curl_close($api);

    var_dump($resp);
```